# How to set initial value that is reference to an object

Tags: python, django

We are trying to set object as an initial value (image, it is a foreign key to an Image). We just cannot make it work, we are always getting NULL/blank value instead. Thanks for any help!

from views.py

```
    def create_comment(request, image_id):
        image = Image.objects.get(id = image_id)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = CreateComment(request.POST, initial={'image':image})
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
        else:
            form = CreateComment()
        return render(request, 'ImagePost/create_comment.html', {'form':form, 'image_id':image_id})
```

from forms.py

```
    class CreateComment(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Comment
            fields = ['user', 'text']
```

from create_comment.html

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <h1>Add comment</h1>
    <form action="{% url 'create_comment' image_id %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
    {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Add">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Where is the image fields in the form class?

Comment: The idea is to not let the user choose that field and force the default value instead. I hope that's possible this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Django 1.9 the `disabled` arguments does exactly what you want:

> The disabled boolean argument, when set to True, disables a form field
>   using the disabled HTML attribute so that it won’t be editable by
>   users. Even if a user tampers with the field’s value submitted to the
>   server, it will be ignored in favor of the value from the form’s
>   initial data.

**Simple example:**

```
class CreateComment(forms.ModelForm):    
    image = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Image.objects.all(), disabled=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['user', 'text', 'image']
```